# Representing more than single object/list CRUD ops with Django REST Framework ViewSets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been writing a game picking style webapp with Django and recently decided to implement my views as API endpoints with DRF, to give me more flexibility when it comes to frontend approaches. I have basic serializers and ViewSets for each of my models, and I can browse them normally with the (excellent) browsable API. Here are a couple:

```
class SheetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer(read_only = True)
  league = LeagueSerializer(read_only = True)
  picks = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    source='pick_set',
    many=True,
    view_name='pick-detail',
    read_only = True
    )

  class Meta:
    model = Sheet
    fields = ('url', 'id', 'league_week', 'user', 'league', 'picks')

class GameSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Game
    fields = ('url', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'week', 'home_team_score', 'away_team_score')

class PickSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  sheet = SheetSerializer()
  game = GameSerializer()
  class Meta:
    model = Pick
    fields = ('url', 'sheet', 'amount', 'spread', 'pick_type', 'pick_team', 'game')
```

With respective ViewSets:

```
class PickViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Pick.objects.all()
  serializer_class = PickSerializer

class GameViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Game.objects.all()
  serializer_class = GameSerializer

class SheetViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Sheet.objects.all()
  serializer_class = SheetSerializer
```

What I'm currently having trouble with is how to represent more complex endpoints than single-object or list of same-type object CRUD operations. For example, I currently have a regular Django view for matchups which pulls the users Sheet (collection of Picks), another users Sheet, and displays the nested Picks against each other. I'm also planning to display other data on the same page from the other users in whatever League they're a part of. The implementation for the user + opponent data in vanilla Django looks like this:

```
class MatchupDetail(DetailView):
  template_name = 'app/matchups.html'
  context_object_name = 'pick_sheet'

  def get_object(self):
    #logic to find and return object

  def get_opponent(self,username,schedule,week, **kwargs):
    #logic to find and return the opponent in the matchup

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #logic to pull the opponents details and set them in the context
```

I've been struggling on how to represent this in a ViewSet. With a regular Django view, it's easy to write the get_object (or get_list) as well as get_context_data, include the user's data + any other desired objects from the database, and pass all of that to the template. Currently, the (early) API endpoint version of the above looks like this:

```
class MatchupViewset(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = SheetSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return Sheet.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

  def list(self, request, format=None):
    sheets = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = SheetSerializer(sheets, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)

  def retrieve(self, request, pk, format=None):
    sheet = Sheet.objects.get(user=self.request.user, league_week=pk)
    serializer = SheetSerializer(sheet, context={'request':request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This code works, but only returns a limited subset of objects- a single users Sheet(s). My aim in this Viewset is to return a list of all the matchups (whi are just a collection of user Sheets) for a given league with `list()` and given league + week with `retrieve()`, but I'm not sure how to return that data. With the normal Django context variable, extra data you include can be named in any manner you like- **how is the goal of collecting and returning an arbitrary number of potentially different objects accomplished with DRF? edit: this wasn't very clear initially- I've gotten nested representation working, but I'm wondering if there's a way to name/label the different serialized objects in the manner that information in the normal context can be set with any name**

Say I want to pass the requesting users serialized Sheet, along with their opponents Sheet and all the other players Sheets for this particular league and week. Will the logic to determine which belongs to the user, which belongs to their opponent, and which are the other players' have to live in the frontend code?

Also, how would I configure the router so that the list() method always requires a URL parameter (for the league)? Anytime I change the registration from

```
router.register(r'matchup', MatchupViewset, base_name = 'matchup')
```

to something like

```
router.register(r'matchup/(?P<league>[0-9]+)/$', MatchupViewset, base_name = 'matchup')
```

the endpoint disappears from the browsable API root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is the goal of collecting and returning an arbitrary number of potentially different objects accomplished with DRF?

I'm not sure what the question is exactly here. I assume you'll want nested representations which is explained [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

> the endpoint disappears from the browsable API root.

This is because the browsable API doesn't know how to resolve the extra kwargs. Since no url matches, he won't display the link

Comment: You're right- I don't think that question was clear. I have nested representations working, but I'm wondering if there's some way to label instances of serialized objects in the way that you can do with the `context ` variable.  

On the URL issue: it makes sense that it doesn't know how to resolve the extra args, I'm just confused on how to specify that they're expected. Since the router handles the Viewset URLs, should an extra be specified in the Viewset somehow?

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers for this though nested routes aren't considered as a best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm pretty sure I'm thinking of the router/URL issue in the wrong way- Viewsets make a lot of things easy, but I'm going to refactor to explicitly map each Viewset method to a concrete view and then register each URL manually. Or use regular APIView based classes instead of Viewsets since it seems that I'm missing something here. Thanks again!